# We are hosting a raffle at work and I was wondering how to calculate probability

Tags: probability

We are hosting a raffle at work and I was wondering how to calculate the chances of winning for ticket purchasers. We are selling 14,000 tickets, there are 11 prizes, and tickets are not replaced when drawn. Please help! :)

Comment: $\dfrac{11}{14000}$ ?

Comment: Isn't that the equation if there is replacement, though? The tickets will not be replaced and the prizes will also decrease as tickets are pulled.

Comment: exactly, see the answer below explaining the logic in @Henry's answer in detail

Answer (score 1):

Probability of getting nothing after the first drawing is $\frac{13999}{14000}$, then getting nothing after the second drawing is $\frac{13999}{14000} \frac{13998}{13999} = \frac{13998}{14000}$, so by analogy you get after 11 drawings
$$
\frac{13999}{14000} \times \frac{13998}{13999}
                    \times \ldots
                    \times \frac{13989}{13990} 
= \frac{13989}{14000}.
$$

Then the probability of winning *something* is $\frac{11}{14000}$.

Comment: So, if someone only bought one ticket, their chance of winning one of the 11 prizes is: 0.00078571? 

What happens if they buy 5 or 10 tickets?

Comment: @Victoria You should really ask that as another question, but I'll post an answer in a few minutes.